# Write XML attributes and namespace declarations in specific order in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I've tried this for a while, and am having trouble writing an XML start element in C# with XmlWriter.

The output line is supposed to look like:
<s:Scenario xmlns:s="./scenarios" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

But the best I've been able to get has been:
<s:Scenario xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="./scenarios" />

with the following code:

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("s", "Scenario", "./scenarios");        
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
```

Is there a better way to write this line? WriteRaw will not work, because this is supposed to be the first line following `xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();`, and it ends up throwing an InvalidOperationException: "Token StartElement in state EndRootElement would result in an invalid XML document. (...)."

Let me know if you need more context! Thanks in advance.

Comment: For a spec-compliant XML parser, attribute order does not matter. Why do you need that particular order of attributes?

Comment: To follow along with @AKX's comment - it doesn't really matter.  You are declaring an element with two namespace attributes.  What else do you need.  As AKX says, attribute order doesn't matter, but the (not-spec-required) canonical order for attributes is alphabetical by name (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML).  That's what you are getting

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize order didn't matter. Thanks for the tip!